# C++ lambda capture by value semantic?

Tags: c++, lambda, constants

```
class TestGetStr {
public:
    string a;
    string getString() {
        return a;
    }
};

void acceptConstString(const string & a) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    auto testGetStr = TestGetStr();

    acceptConstString(testGetStr.getString()); //compile ok

    auto testaaa = [testGetStr](){

//compile error 'this' argument to member function 'getString' has type 'const TestGetStr', but function is not marked const        
acceptConstString(testGetStr.getString());
    };
```

Difference between normal call and lambda capture?

The normal call can compile, but the lambda call can't compile.

And Why? Thanks for more detail.

Comment: Lambdas are `const` by default. You need to explicitly mark it as `mutable` - `auto testaaa = [testGetStr]() mutable {...}`. Or, better, mark `getString()` as `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `mutable` qualifier.

```
auto testaaa = [testGetStr]() mutable {
//                            ^^^^^^^
    acceptConstString(testGetStr.getString());
};
```

Otherwise the `operator()` of the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is const-qualified, and then can't call non-const member functions on the captured object.

> - **mutable**: allows *body* to modify the objects captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions
>
> Unless the keyword `mutable` was used in the lambda-expression, the
> function-call operator is const-qualified and the objects that were
> captured by copy are non-modifiable from inside this `operator()`.

PS: Or better to make `TestGetStr::getString()` const member function.